# Grails View thinks model is null

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I have a Grails 3 app and I'm trying to use a view to marshall the output of my controller into a specific format. I add two views: 1. a model tied to the controller action under `views/order/getOrderLines.gson` and 2. a template for individual orderLines `views/order/_orderLines.gson`

However my output comes back as an empty object. It is really difficult to figure out. Here are my views:
`views/order/getOrderLines.gson`

```
model {
  List<OrderLine> orderLinesList
}
json tmpl.orderLines(orderLinesList)
```

`views/order/_orderLine.gson`

```
model {
  OrderLine orderLine
}
json {
  id orderLine.id
  description orderLine.description
  ...
}
```

But I get a `NullPointerException` on `orderLine`, as if there was not a `List<OrderLine>` being returned from the `OrderController`. When I delete these views, the output returns just as expected, although it isn't marshalled the way I'd like it to be.

**The weirdest thing**: this works for most of my other views. I found a lot of great documentation at [Grails Views' documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-views/latest/) but nothing seems to be covering this strange error.

Comment: Do you have two templates?

In your question you refer to _orderLine.gson and to _orderLines.gson, which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper way of working with templates should be like this:

File `_orderLine.gson`

```
import com.example.OrderLine

model{
    OrderLine orderLine
}

json{
    id orderLine.id
    description orderLine.description
    ...
}
```

File `getOrderLines.gson`

```
import com.example.OrderLine

model{
    Iterable<OrderLine> orderLineList
}

json tmpl.orderLine(orderLineList ?: [])
```

Notice singular `orderLineList` not `orderLinesList`, same with variable name `orderLine` not `orderLines`

As `sct999` said, name of model variable is same as used template name. But that is just by default. You can even be this explicit:

`g.render(template:'<path to template>', collection: <your collection>, var: '<target variable>')`

Comment: marked this one correct because just had to change `orderLinesList` to `orderLineList`: the variable name was really it. GAH! Took me way too long!

Comment: Is there documentation anywhere that shows how the model List parameters need to be named?

Comment: I'm not aware of any guidelines how to name them. I think there are only some small restrictions so collections could be automatically matched. If you use explicit call (like last example code in my answer), then you can name parameters or variables as you need.

Answer (score 2):

In case your template name is `_orderLines.gson` you should rename your model variable in `_orderLines.gson` from `orderLine` to `orderLines`.

So your `_orderLines.gson` template would look like this

```
model {
  OrderLine orderLines
}
json {
  id orderLines.id
  description orderLines.description
  ...
}
```

As http://grails.github.io/grails-views/latest/#_templates says

> The name of the model variable is the same as the template name.

So, your model variable should be `orderLines` (same as template name) not `orderLine`